# Is there some kind of wrapper that would allow bluetooth to communicate with web app? Using native build to hold wrapper of course

Tags: ios, web-applications, bluetooth, progressive-web-apps

I need to quickly redo my ios app and need to have it on the web and android. From my experience, my web apps have always been the best. The issue is, it needs access to Bluetooth, which I know is not supported directly.

Before I hire new developers for an emergency build from scratch, would it be possible to do the following: Make an ios app that uses UIWebKit, when Bluetooth is needed, somehow it tells the native app to use native API to talk to Bluetooth BLE device, then sends the results back to the web app?

I have heard of wrappers for reactJS, but I am most experienced with PHP and RoR web apps.

What do you think? Are there any suggestions that you have that would let me build for IOS, Android, Web and uses Bluetooth (through native programming of course, not web Bluetooth).

Comment: Are you saying that you have looked at Web Bluetooth https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/ and you are discounting it?
If you have the Chrome browser on your device (or Chromium on Raspberry Pi), then go to chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices and have a play.

Comment: Not discounting it. This is an iOS app, and from my understanding web Bluetooth is not supported on iOS at this time. Am I incorrect? Thank you!

Comment: My understanding is that on iOS you currently have to use a different browser: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/webble/id1193531073

Comment: True, that browser can do it. But that is not my app. My app needs to be a standalone download from the App Store.